# Performing joins on very large data sets

Tags: csv, join, bigdata

I have received several CSV files that I need to merge into a single file, all with a common key I can use to join them. Unfortunately, each of these files are about 5 GB in size (several million rows, about 20-100+ columns), so it's not feasible to just load them up in memory and execute a join against each one, but I do know that I don't have to worry about existing column conflicts between them.

I tried making an index of the row for each file that corresponded to each ID so I could just compute the result without using much memory, but of course that's slow as time itself when actually trying to look up each row, pull the rest of the CSV data from the row, concatenate it to the in-progress data and then write out to a file. This simply isn't feasible, even on an SSD, to process against the millions of rows in each file.

I also tried simply loading up some of the smaller sets in memory and running a parallel.foreach against them to match up the necessary data to dump back out to a temporary merged file. While this was faster than the last method, I simply don't have the memory to do this with the larger files.

I'd ideally like to just do a full left join of the largest of the files, then full left join to each subsequently smaller file so it all merges.

How might I otherwise go about approaching this problem? I've got 24 gb of memory on this system to work with and six cores to work with.

While this might just be a problem to load up in a relational database and do the join there from, I thought I'd reach out before going that route to see if there are any ideas out there on solving this from my local system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A relational database is the first thing that comes to mind and probably the easiest, but barring that...

Build a hash table mapping key to file offset. Parse the rows on-demand as you're joining. If your keyspace is still too large to fit in available address space, you can put that in a file too. This is exactly what a database index would do (though maybe with a b-tree).

You could also pre-sort the files based on their keys and do a merge join.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that "several" 5GB files is not a tremendous amount of data. I know it's relative, but the way you describe your system...I still think it's not a big deal. If you weren't needing to join, you could use Perl or a bunch of other command-liney tools.

Are the column names known in each file? Do you care about the column names?

My first thoughts:

1. Spin up Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic MapReduce (EMR) instance (even a pretty small one will work)
2. Upload these files
3. Import the files into Hive (as managed or not).
4. Perform your joins in Hive.

You can spinup an instance in a matter of minutes and be done with the work within an hour or so, depending on your comfort level with the material.

I don't work for Amazon, and can't even use their stuff during my day job, but I use it quite a bit for grad school. It works like a champ when you need your own big data cluster. Again, this isn't "Big Data (R)", but Hive will kill this for you in no time.

This article doesn't do exactly what you need (it copies data from S3); however, it will help you understand table creation, etc.
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5249664154115844

**Edit:**
Here's a link to the EMR overview:
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are manipulating the data. But if just combining the csv's you could try this...
http://www.solveyourtech.com/merge-csv-files/

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a need for joining it against the key (which is thankfully in the first column of all files), so I can't simply concatenate everything, but thanks!